# C++ confusing with Dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, oop, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
_Groups = (group **) new char[sizeof (group **) * NOMGRPS];
```

The above is the actual code I read.I just wonder what is the diff if I do

```
_Groups = new group*[sizeof (group **) * NOMGRPS];
```

Comment: I don't understand why the downvotes. The question is specific and valid, yet there are people who felt it is easier to criticize than to enlighten.

Comment: The first one looks suspicious, and the second one is almost a guarantee that you're doing something wrong. Other than that, your question is impossible to answer without knowing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It is the same as the first one, and I never said either lines were invalid. It's just code that you usually don't see in real life. If you're looking for an explanation of the syntax, the first line dynamically allocates enough memory to contain 10 pointers to type `Point`. The second allocates enough memory to contain 10 `char`s and then casts the result to a pointer to pointer to `Point`. I honestly cannot think of a reason why anyone would do the latter.

Comment: @Praetorian: I just posted the actual code I read.Could you tell me whether the actual code I read got any diff with the one i just edited in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_Groups = (group **) new char[sizeof (group **) * NOMGRPS];
```

This creates enough space for `NOMGRPS` group pointers and casts it to a pointer to a `group**`, presumably to be used as an array of pointers to objects of type `group` that are allocated elsewhere.  This is (or more strictly speaking, was) a common idiom as `char` is almost always a single byte, so this says "Allocate `sizeof (group **) * NOMGRPS` bytes (enough bytes for `NOMGRPS` group pointers) and cast it to a pointer to a group pointer.  So if `NOMGRPS` is 10, and you are on a 32 bit system, with 4 byte pointers, this allocates 40 bytes.

```
_Groups = new group*[sizeof (group **) * NOMGRPS];
```

Here instead of saying you want 40 `char`s (i.e. bytes) you are saying you want 40 `group*`.  So if `NOMGRPS` is 10, and you are on a 32 bit system, with 4 byte pointers, this allocates 40 * 4 or 160 bytes.  This is almost certainly not what you want, but since it overallocates memory, it will likely work fine.  Your instincts to make this change are right.  Any time you cast in modern C++, you should consider it suspect.  But you didn't quite go far enough.

What you really want is this:

```
_Groups = new group*[NOMGRPS];
```

`new` knows the size of a `group*` and thus will allocate enough for `NOMGRPS` of them.  This is more correct than the original version which used `new char`.

Comment: Hi,Steven thanks for your explanation.As I am still very new to c++ I still not really understand these.As for me I just know the basic concept of dynamic allocation. I like to understand thing in graphical view where I know you are not going to do that for me. So if i refering to this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5gUlnrUqqQ is this graphical explanation can give me a better view?

Comment: Btw can i say:
_Groups = new group*[NOMGRPS]; is wqual to _Groups = (group **) new char[sizeof (group **) * NOMGRPS]; ?

Comment: Yes, generally.  It likely compiles to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand intention of this code. My guess is it's to allocate memory for `NOMGRPS` pointers to `group`, i.e. you need (`NOMGRPS` * size of pointer) bytes of memory.

---

If so, then this

```
_Groups = (group **) new char[sizeof (group **) * NOMGRPS];
```

does what you want. In wrong way though.
It allocates memory for (`NOMGRPS` * size of pointer) chars. Size of `char` is 1 byte, that's why this line does what you want. But:

1) You need to allocate memory for pointers, not chars.

2) You need to allocate memory for `group *` pointers, not `group **`. So `sizeof (group **)` is wrong.

---

```
_Groups = new group*[sizeof (group **) * NOMGRPS];
```

This allocates memory for (`NOMGRPS` * size of pointer) pointers, which is not what you want.

---

The valid way:

```
_Groups = new group *[ NOMGRPS ];
```

It allocates memory for `NOMGRPS` pointers to `group`. Mission accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

`(Point **) new char[10]` allocates memory for ten `char`s, then converts the pointer to a pointer to `Point*`. This is likely to crash if `sizeof(char) != sizeof(Point*)` because the allocated array will be the wrong size. So it is plain wrong.

Comment: Actually the actual code i was reading should be this one  _Groups = (group **) new char[sizeof (group **) * NOMGRPS];  But i simplified the array size to 10.

Comment: Ah, that's very different.  "Simplifying" it to a size of ten changes it from reasonable to bizarre.